# PDF generation on iPhone, size of mediaBox

Tags: iphone, pdf

When creating a PDF, when you create the mediabox, how do you know what size you want to create it?  If I want it to fit a standard 8.5x11 paper so I could email it to someone and they could print it, do I make the mediaBox to be 850,1100?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in mediaBox are points (1/72th of an inch). For letter paper use 612,792 (8.5*72, 11*72).